# PHP/jQuery (AUTOCOMPLETE) invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I've got a problem in my foreach saying "Invalid argument supplied for foreach in line ..."

This is the code I'm working on:

```
    protected function jsGenerateResourcesAutocomplete(){
    $employeeNames = $this->employeeNames;
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<script>' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= 'var employeeNames = [' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach( $employeeNames as $employeeName ){
        $html .= '"' . $employeeName->getEmployeeName() . '",' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $html .= '];' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '$(function() {' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '$(#resource-input input:text").each(function() {' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '$(this).autocomplete({source: employeeNames});' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '})' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '})' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '</script>' . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

In this line: **foreach( $employeeNames as $employeeName ){** throws the error. What is wrong with this?

Comment: What is $this->employeeNames? Where does it come from? in other word what's the print_r of $this->employeeNames?

Comment: maybe `$employeeNames` is not in `Array` format or doesn't contain any values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly please check $employeeNames this is array or not using

```
  is_array($employeeNames)
```

then execute foreach loop